# Replace single quote in QFile file name

Tags: c++, file, qt

I want open a file which contains single quote but I can't open it.

**File name example :** `QFile file("my'file.example")`

I've tried with `file.fileName().replace("\'", "\\\'")` but it's the same result.

Comment: are you sure the file is there? How do you know the file is not open?

Comment: I know with `if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to replace `"\'"` but it is not on the original string so it will not work. Furthermore, `QFile::filename` return a copy of the filename property, and any modification (like `replace`) will be made on the copy. To play with the filename (before open), use

```
file.setFilename(file.fileName().myModificationOperation())
```

Have you tried with `QFile file("my\'file.example")`?

to test your parameter use the static call:

```
QString filename = "my\'file.example";
bool okay = QFile::exists(filename);
```

Comment: Ok but the filename is dynamic, so I can do that only with a function. setFilename works perfectly, thanks.